# Does a master session exist for java Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create a page that updates for all viewers of that particular page when anther page is updated

So one person could watch the page on a phone and another person could view the exact same page on their computer (updated in sync)

i.e. (Student Ceremony) there is a ceremony, and when a QR is scanned (on a different page) I want the ceremony page to update the content on that (other) page with the student's information (pulled from database)

Comment: You need push notifications - something happens and the server send notifications to all users. Take a look at [this](https://dev.to/marcushellberg/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-in-java-21lo)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: https://github.com/Atmosphere

Comment: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/server-push

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.